# Where are Autodesk Forge and AWS cloud service servers located for EU subscriptions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autodesk-forge

We are considering to develop applications utilizing Autodesk Forge. Our customers may want to know the physical location of the Autodesk Forge cloud and the underlying AWS cloud servers (that is, the data centers). Is it so that the servers are currently located in US only? Is it possible for the developers to select the location of the data center to be e.g. in EU? How about the rest of the world?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently Forge servers in the US and in Europe. When storing data on the Forge (OSS) storage system , you can specify on which server your bucket is created (and hence where objects in that bucket are stored). See the description of the 'x-ads-region' header parameter at https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/.